# Heroku: App Crashed with H10 Error code. Can't resolve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

My app runs locally but when deployed to Heroku crashes. Any help?

Sorry for the formatting. Don't know how to properly do this...

```
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Admin::ResourceController (NameError)
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spree_essential_cms-0.2.1/app/controllers/admin/contents_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:417:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `each'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `each'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `eager_load!'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:412:in `eager_load!'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-07-03T08:56:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-07-03T08:56:03+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: The first two lines show the issues "uninitialized constant Admin::ResourceController" in the contents_controller.rb. Did you try to run the app in production mode with the same environment as Heroku (Ruby 1.9.1) ? It may help debug the issue.

Comment: Are you using rails_admin or activeadmin gems? Looks like ActiveAdmin, but I can't be sure. I seem to remember having this issue and it has something to do with the dashboard being evaluated during bootup. You might need to add a :require to your gemfile, but not sure.